# Android ListView setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, drawer

I am trying to make a ListView with TextViews, I want each textview to be able to be clicked and based on it's position a Fragment is pulled up. However, the itemOnClickListener seems to not even be called.

```
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.devices_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerInfo));
    mDrawerList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int pos, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CLICKED " + pos);
            selectDevice(pos);
        }
    });
```

here's the xml for the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/deviceText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

List view xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/devices_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml file that is containing `ListView`...

Comment: @Shajeel Afzal Alright I posted it above.

Comment: I think you should specify `match_parent` instead of `240dp` in `android:layout_width`, can i ask you why you are doing so?

Answer (score 5):

It's your whole xml drawer (I presume you try to do a navigation drawer) ? If you have a parent layout check the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` otherwise you have to wrap your textview in a layout (LinearLayout is sufficient if you don't have a complex UI for the item). 
The `new OnItemClickListener` is an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListerner`?

(An excellent how-to http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_navigation_drawer )

Comment: @JordanBit Hey I changed my list_item.xml, take a look at it above.

Comment: Also, I've changed my code a little to represent your tutorial. And now when I create the ArrayAdapter it's saying I need to give it a TextView resource id, but I am...
`  mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fragment_layout, R.id.txtPls, drawerInfo));
`

Comment: I try to understand why it's not working. When you try without the TextView parameter what is happenning ?

Comment: @JordinBit also where do I put 'android:descendantFocusability...' Which xml block?

Comment: I tried giving it only the layout, not the text view it said this:

08-14 12:13:19.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3571): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: Can you make a Gist with your actual code ? The android:descendendantFocusability is in the the LinearLayout for your item but at least it's not really useful if you don't need a specific layout for your list item (like multiple items on the same line etc).

Comment: What do you mean by Gist?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35387/discussion-between-user1656122-and-jordanblt)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using `mDrawerList.setItemsCanFocus(false);`? You don't have any focusable items in your item layout, so it's safe to remove that call. Should work ok after that.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But I've encountered a new problem. I've change the just plain textview to a TextView wrapped in a linear layout and now it's saying I need a TextViewID, when I create the array Adapter.

mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fragment_layout, R.id.txtPls, drawerInfo));

Comment: Any more help would be helpful.

Comment: Well, what's the problem? You already have the id, from the code above: `@+id/deviceText`. Also, `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fragment_layout` <-- this doesn't look right, are you sure your item's layout file is called `fragment_layout`? It used to be `drawer_list_item` in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you are using Button in list row item, it'll over-ride you list item click event

Answer (score 0):

For list items inside your list.. you have to set the attributes below

android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"